# Interrupt present in /proc/interrupt file after free_irq

Tags: linux-kernel

I have registered an interrupt using

```
/* Request INT and set the handler*/
err = request_irq(irq_num, gpio_irq_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_LOW  | IRQF_SHARED, "Test_IRQ", dev);
```

and when I exit the module I free it using

```
free_irq(irq_num, dev);
```

The problem I face is the interrupt is never cleared from the /proc/interrupts file

I have registered the interrupts here for a gpio

```
root@lolly:~# insmod isr.ko 
root@lolly:~# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
165:        701          0         -   5  Test_IRQ
Err:          0
```

I remove the module and the interrupt is free

```
root@lolly:~# rmmod isr.ko 
root@lolly:~# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
165:        701          0         -   5
Err:          0
```

But I find the entry and the count

I again load the module

```
root@lolly:~# insmod isr.ko 
root@lolly:~# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
165:        702          0         -   5  Test_IRQ
Err:          0
```

and I see the count is still not zero

I cause a 102 interrupts

```
root@lolly:~# cat /proc/interrupts 
           CPU0       CPU1       
165:        804          0         -   5  Test_IRQ
Err:          0
root@lolly:~#
```

But the number is incremented

Is this behavior correct? I expect the interrupt entry to disappear when the IRQ is freed and to count from zero when loaded again

Could any body please correct me on my observations?

Comment: Yeah, there is not enough context. Could you provide a skeleton of your driver?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used interrupts in the kernel (yet), but I took some time looking through the kernel searching.

The `remove_irq` function essentially just calls [`__free_irq`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/irq/manage.c#L1285).

In this function, the following happen:

1. The handler being removed is searched and found
2. The handler is removed
3. [`irq_pm_remove_action`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/irq/pm.c#L51) is called which doesn't have anything to do with `/proc` either.
4. If no more handlers (`desc->action == NULL`), `irq_shutdown` is called, which is arch specific (doesn't do anything on x86) and unrelated to `/proc`
5. [`unregister_handler_proc`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/irq/proc.c#L384) is called, but this seems to only try to remove `/proc/interrupts` altogether if there is absolutely no interrupts left to report
6. Stop the IRQ thread (which you don't use) and remove the module (if it were still in memory (even after `rmmod`) because the handler was still in memory (I guess)).

The [`show_interrupts`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/irq/proc.c#L431) function indeed [checks](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/irq/proc.c#L465) for whether any handlers exist. So to answer your first question:

> Is this behavior correct?

No, you are not supposed to see that interrupt, because nobody is attached to it anymore.

If I may guess, is it possible that on an early version of your module, you forgot to `remove_irq`, so a previous installation of the irq handler is left in the kernel? A restart could solve this problem.

Note that `IRQF_SHARED` interrupts are `remove_irq`ed by looking for the `dev` pointer. So if you remove the module without `remove_irq`, there is no un-hack-ish way of removing the handler.